# Fluid dynamics between with 3 infinite planes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy, waves, viscosity

I've been studying the dynamic of a fluid trapped between two infinite plates at speeds $v_1$ and $v_2$. So far, I understand that between those two plates, the velocity of the particles in the fluid is:
$$\frac{\delta^2 v_x}{\delta z^2}=\frac{1}{\eta }\frac{\delta p}{\delta x}$$
where $\frac{\delta p}{\delta x}$ represents the pressure gradient with respect to $x$. We've analyzed how we can find the velocity, flow rate and the potencial energy dissipated by the system at each point (x,z) between the two plates.

But what happens if I add a third infinite plate (or an infinite number of plates, for that matter), between the initial two, at a certain velocity $v_3$?

I can't really find any solved exercises with that scenario (if you know of any, that would be really helpful), so I suppose this is a superposition of the case with 2 plates.

But I'd be really interested in understanding what happens. And how does the dissipated potential ($p=f_s v_x$) change in that scenario, assuming there is no pressure gradient?

Comment: Is $v_3$ fixed? If so, then you just have two independent two-plate problems, as far as I see it. If it's a free variable between the two plates of fixed velocities, then you still have two two-plate problems, but you need to integrate from plate1 to plate3, and then from plate3 to plate2. $v_3$ might not be solvable then, you may need another condition, like that no pressure is communicated from each side of $v_3$ to the other.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that we choose a velocity for the third plane, so that makes sense. What I still don't get though is how the "dissipated" potential energy within the fluid changes, since to "keep" the third plate at that velocity, the system has to dispend energy, right? Otherwise the velocity of the third plane would just be dictated by the flow rate imposed by the system

Comment: Well, there would be stresses on the plate, trying to move it, as long as the velocities just above and below it are different from its own velocity. This would then perform work on the plate and accelerate it. However, by 'holding' $v_3$ at a fixed value, one implicitly assumes some momentum sink. It's as if at the 'end' of the infinite plate somebody would hold it and push against it. This persons muscles would then need to bring up the work against the push of the stresses.